# Cannot save check_box_tag data with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, sqlite, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I am trying to save checkbox data in project table

In Project Controller

```
 def new
    @project = Project.new
    @allTags = Tag.all
    @allBenefits = Benefit.all
  end



 def create
    p params[:projectName]; # this always throws nil even there is a value
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    #@tagging = @project.tagging.create!(:project=>Project.id,:tag=>1)

    if @project.save
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def project_params
     params.require(:com_a_b_c_project).permit(:projectName, :briefDesc, :whatSection, :challengers, :status, :valueProposal, :maturityLevel,:tag_ids =>[])
  end
```

In Project new view

```
<h4><label for = "tags">Tags</label></h4>

<% @allTags.each do |tag| %>
    <p><%= f.label tag.tagName %></p>
    <%= check_box_tag :tag_ids, tag.id, @project.tags.include?(tag), :name => 'project[tag_ids][]'-%>
 <%end%>



class Com::a::b::c::Project < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :taggings 
     has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags 
    end

class Com::a::b::c::Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings 
 has_many :projects, :through => :taggings
end


class Com::a::b::c::Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

On my logs I get tag_ids parameter as below

```
project"=>{"tag_ids"=>["1", "2"]}
```

> Q. Do I have to save data to Tagging table separately or does it automatically saves data because of the associations in the table?

Currently nothing get saved on the tagging table. How can I store tagging data?

Comment: `tag_ids` are supposed to be saved in which table ? Associations do not store data in related table , you can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: I have added accepts_nested_attributes_for on tagging table but still nothings saving...

Comment: By adding  @project.taggings.build to ProjectsController with accepts_nested_attributes_for to models finally stored the records with project_id. But the tag_ids are still not getting stored in tagging table.

Answer (score 0):

if i follow correctly

```
class Com::a::b::c::Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :taggings 
 has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags 
end
```

on project model should allow this to be persisted.

Comment: I have added the suggestions to Project ActiveRecord. But still nothing get persist